# How to use `where` and `in` clause together in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables:

1) Users
 2) Trustmembers

I want to take all userId's from Trustmembers and compare with Id of Users table and then i want to print all the names from Users table of matching id's.

In sql I can write the query like

```
select name from users where Id IN(select userId from Trustmembers);
```

How to write the same query in Model(MVC) of php codeigniter to get the same result?

Or any other way except using Where_in??

Comment: reffer this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405635/convert-simple-select-statement-from-php-to-mvc-php

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

**METHOD 1:**

```
$this->db->select('name')->from('users');
$this->db->where('Id IN (SELECT userId FROM `Trustmembers`)', NULL, FALSE);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

`NULL, false` will be used to not escape the query as by default.

**METHOD 2**

```
$this->db->select('name')->from('users');
$this->db->where_in('Id', 'SELECT userId FROM `Trustmembers`');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

**METHOD 3** : [subquery library](http://labs.nticompassinc.com/CodeIgniter-Subqueries/)

```
$this->db->select('name')->from('users');
$subquery = $this->subquery->start_subquery('where_in');
$subquery->select('userId')->from('Trustmembers');
$this->subquery->end_subquery('Id', FALSE);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: codeigniter has this->db->where_in() https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in

Comment: Codeigniter provides where_in() , where_not_in() etc. we can use those functions also.

Comment: @Bhavin : I think above three ways will be enough, may be there are still more !

Comment: I tried all the three methods but not getting the required result

Comment: what errors are you getting, I am sure, you havent tried last one, it need thats library to include in yours

Comment: I m getting error by saying "Call to a member function start_subquery() on null"

Comment: Yes because as I said, you need to include that library subquery to make it work, but yes, you can try first two, can you tell me what error you are getting in them

Comment: Before i wrote query like     "$q=$this->db->select('users.name')
     ->join('trustmembers','users.id=trustmembers.userId')
     ->where(['users.id'=>$id])
     ->get('users');
     
  return ($q->num_rows()>0)? $q->result_array():array();
  "  But it is getting only a single value

Comment: where this query came from, your question is different and you're posting different code in here. Your comment has only one userid specified, thats Y one record you are getting, but thats nothing to do with your question you asked

Comment: I said i have one column as userId but it can have multiple values right, In the sense i have to take all those values and compare with each Id one by one and fetch the matching results